# Fabric + DigitalOcean: unvisible ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE?

Tags: flask, environment-variables, fabric, digital-ocean

I have server on DigitalOcean and I use fabric for deploying my code. And my code is dependent on environment variables (flask config). I've faced one strange trouble today: on server in **/root/.bashrc** I've added next line

```
export CONFIG=/path/to/conf
```

And when I executing on remote console

```
>>> echo $CONFIG
>>> /path/to/conf  # result, as it should be
```

But in **fabfile** I have a function

```
def show():
    run("echo $CONFIG")
```

And it prints an empty string. WHY?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be the case, as by default Fabric uses the `-l` flag which is supposed to `Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell (see INVOCATION below).`

I am also not able to reproduce your issue:

```
$ fab -H home test_bash
[home] Executing task 'test_bash'
[home] run: grep FOO $HOME/.bashrc
[home] out: export FOO="BAR"
[home] out:

[home] run: echo $FOO
[home] out: BAR
[home] out:
```

So my guess is that you've changed the `env.shell`, or that you're not connecting as the `root` user which is where you're setting this bash export. (Note that `run()` isn't the same a `sudo()` in Fabric usage)