# Remote environment variable from file with Fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I am trying to just do a simple echo $MYVAR on a remote server with Fabric.

The environment variable is in my ~/.bashrc file on the remote host.

I have tried:

```
run("source /home/<myusername>/.bashrc && echo $MYVAR")
```

This just prints an empty string.  Running it when logged in on the remote machine prints "5", the value in the bashrc file.  Does anyone know why this would be?

I need the environment variable to be set from a file on the remote host, and not decided by Fabric.

I am running the ssh commands as `<myusername>`, so the username seems correct.  This seems like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624811/fabric-digitalocean-unvisible-environment-variable), except that maybe they were running things as the wrong user.  I also tried the `shell` argument to `run`, with no luck.

I haven't tried the various context manager-ish things, as they just seem to be a shorthand for command1 && command2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [as explained in the answer you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22734611/396967), fabric uses a *login shell*, **not** and *interactive shell*, meaning your `~/.bahsrc` is not going to be source'd on the remote. You should export your variable in your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`.

Without the relevant content of your remote `~/.bashrc` it's impossible to tell why your command fails.

Comment: I likely will not be able to revisit this for a while, but I didn't know there was a difference between ~/.bashrc file and ~/.bash_profile.  I was used to seeing the 'profile' on my Mac, and 'rc' on some Ubuntu systems I use, but I thought they were just different names for the same thing.  I found [this explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment) somewhat helpful. Thanks!